# Is there any info about further destination of troops exiting Afganistan?

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, society, afghanistan

As US troops leaving Afganistan, it seems interesting to know where would they go.

Returning home huge amount of veterans (returning from a **lost** conflict) can influence inner politics drastically - like was after Vietnam.

Is there any information about it?

Comment: You should consider your assumption that a *huge* amount of troops will be going anywhere, and inform yourself better. [This piece](https://abcnews.go.com/International/fear-uncertainty-meet-us-troop-withdrawal-announcement-afghanistan/story?id=74255577) from november 2020 (when the withdrawal agreement was signed) talks about some 4.500 soldiers in Afghanistan. Granted, many more have served through the years, but those others are already somewhere else.

Comment: @SJuan76, yes and no. Nowadays western society is much more sensitive to human losses.

Comment: Where do you think they would go, other than to their bases in the US?

Comment: Funny assumption. Middle east bases, korean/japanese bases?

Comment: Note, I wouldn't compare the US involvement in Afganistan with Vietnam, it's comparing oranges with bananas. One was lost (Vietnam), the other is unsuccessful and tired. You shall consider taking that comparison out to make the question sounds better.

Comment: This is a military question and not a political one as it involves how the military is going to  deal with troop allocation. There is no reason at all to think that there will be politics in were they will go.

Answer (score 5):

The numbers need to be taken into perspective.  To cite a [2020 BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-54980141) about withdrawals:

> In Iraq, the number of US troops will be cut by 500 to 2,500, while the number of service personnel in Afghanistan will fall from 4,500 to about 2,500.

So at most we are talking 4500 soldiers, hardly anything to *influence inner politics*.  You may have other reasons to ask this question, but the one given doesn't hold water.

Actually, [this article, April 2021](https://www.cfr.org/in-brief/biden-afghanistan-troop-withdrawal-september-11), puts number at 3500 remaining until their departure.

If I were Biden I'd hate to have to provide *political*, rather than *military*, justifications on why they could not just return home.

The other aspect is the location of Afghanistan.  It's landlocked and [none of the neighbors are all that US-useful](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2021/06/07/is-there-a-place-for-a-us-military-base-in-central-asia-a74127) (though I thought one of the northern Stans had a US base before).  Seeing there is no great way to keep tabs on Afghanistan from its neighbors, tendency will be to pull exiting troops waaaay back.

Politically, the nature of the departing US troops is also very different from Vietnam.  This lot is an all-volunteer, professional, army who initially went in to go after the 9/11 perpetrators and peaked at [100K in 2011](https://www.militarytimes.com/news/your-military/2016/07/06/a-timeline-of-u-s-troop-levels-in-afghanistan-since-2001/).  While the Vietnam war involved a lot of unwilling draftees being put into an easy-to-criticize war that saw gradual US piecemeal buildup, up to [560K in 1968, right around Tet](https://www.americanwarlibrary.com/vietnam/vwatl.htm), punctuated by Westmoreland's frequent "gimme 20K more boys and this war is done".

Apparently, the last major units *partially* on rotation there are the [101st Airborne](https://www.army.mil/article/247919/receiving_onward_movement_of_afghanistan_withdraw_operations) and [10th Mountain divisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10th_Mountain_Division).  10th is based in NY, with [USCENTCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Central_Command) tasking.  [101st](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101st_Airborne_Division) is in Kentucky.  So, perhaps rather than just "home", those units will return to the US and/or to whatever US bases outside of the US they usually are assigned to.

Comment: Also, veterans have been returning from Afghanistan continuously. Many thousands have served a term there and returned.

Comment: Yes, it's true. But this is the first time from Saigon when retreating is done that fast, with levaing bases secretly, at night. So, that would definitely affect mood of those people.

Comment: Retreat at night and pre-announced has been a standard ploy of US forces in forward bases throughout Afghanistan.  Nothing the troops are not used to.

Comment: @user2501323 The US military has possibly the best night vision equipment in the world, they do everything they can at night to take full advantage of this fact.